# Get terms in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to get the terms of taxonomy portfolio in functions.php by a function, but it's not working.

```
$terms_array = array();
function portfolio_terms() {
    $terms = get_terms('portfolio_category');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $terms_array[] = $term->name;
    }
    return $terms_array;
}
add_action('init', 'portfolio_terms', 9999);

var_dump(portfolio_terms());
```

When I change terms portfolio_category to only category it's working, also portfolio_category taxonomy is coming from a plugin portfolio post type.

This is the error im getting: *Trying to get property of non-object*

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no problem at all with your portfolio_terms functions. All it does is sort through provided array, and error is completely different. Actually, the error message is quite straightforward, some item(s) where in array is not an object(s), and so you are trying to get property of non-object. So, what is happening here, is what your get_terms function returns something which is not object, so the problem is in there. You can check what exactly get_terms returns with var_dump and when debug that function. So as far as I am able to tell from that code what the problem is either in get_terms or the plugin.

Comment: Well, when I'm changing portfolio_category to category, it's working. It returns an array with all categories. 

I've changed the code only to get terms, but still no success.